# PHP and PDO Not working in MAMP 4.1.1. with PHP 7.0.15

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mamp

I just installed MAMP 4.1.1 and I think I have everything configured the way I want. I switched to PFP 7.0.15 so I could use phpMyAdmin and I can connect to mySQL with this code:

```
<?php

// Read in db connection details
$config_ini = parse_ini_file("../include/config.ini",true);

// mySQL server connection info
$servername = $config_ini['mySQL_db']['servername'];
$dbname = $config_ini['mySQL_db']['dbname'];
$port = $config_ini['mySQL_db']['port'];
$username = $config_ini['Online_User']['username'];
$password = $config_ini['Online_User']['password'];

$dsn = "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;port=$port;charset=utf8mb4";

// set the PDO error mode to exception
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
);

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
           echo "Connection successful!";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

I see 'Connection successful!' in my browser.

But when I open a page that worked just fine with my Mac Apache server and an earlier version of PHP, I get no query results with this code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="contest-year" name="year" size="1" required>
    <option value="<?php echo date("Y");?>"><?php echo date("Y");?></option>
    <?php
    include_once("../../include/connect_pdo.php");

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Year from tblmodelentry_online WHERE Year <> YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY Year DESC";
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['Year']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Year']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
    }
    $conn=null;
    ?>
</select>
```

All I see in the dropdown is

> ">

What am I doing wrong? There's nothing in my /Applications/MAMP/log files.

Comment: Did you look at the HTML source? Is there something wrong with the output or is it just echoing nothing?

Comment: Is the first script you show the `connect_pdo.php` script that you include in the second script

Comment: Why are you echo "Connection successful!"; in your connect_pdo.php file? that's going to mess up your `<select>` element since it's echoing it within that element.

Comment: Machavity - I'm using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 to edit my files and I don't see any HTML errors.

Comment: RiggsFolly - no, that's just a copy/paste into a new test.php file.

Comment: @Augwa - that was just in my separate test.php file. In connect_pdo.php file there is no echo.